# Equal words in regular expression in Matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

I want to make regular expression like this `'(a)stack(a)'`, where `a = '\w*'`, for finding all the words in the given text, which looks like these, for example: `"(sir)stack(sir)"`, `"(actually)stack(actually)"`.

Is there any way for doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can repeat a capture group by referencing it with `\` followed by the number of the capture group. So:

```
\(
 (\w*)  # capture group 1
\)
stack
\(
 \1     # repeat capture group 1
\)
```

http://regex101.com/r/dS6aW6